# How do I use the "return" value of one method in another method

Tags: java, methods, return-value

I am currently working on this project that plays the high low dice game.  I am stuck on how to use the returned `char` from `getHighLow` and the returned `int` from `getBet` and `getRoll` in `determineWinnings`.  This is my first year learning Java currently, so any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int currentPool = 100;
    getBet(keyboard, currentPool);
    getHighLow(keyboard);
    getRoll();
    >>  determineWinnings(highLow, userBet, rollSum);


}

// Given a Scanner and a current maximum amount of money, prompt the user for
// an integer representing the number of dollars that they want to bet. This
// number must be between 0 and to maximum number of dollars. If the user enters
// a number that is out of bounds, display an error message and ask again.
// Return the bet to the calling program.
private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int currentPool) {
    int userBet = -1;
    while (userBet == -1) {
        inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("You have $" + currentPool);
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
        userBet = inScanner.nextInt();
        if (userBet > currentPool || userBet < 0) {
            System.out.println("Your bet MUST be between 0 and " + currentPool + " dollars");
            userBet = -1;
        }
        if (userBet == 0) {
            System.out.println("You have " + currentPool + " dollars left.");
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
    return userBet;
}

// Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a single character indicating whether
// they
// would like to bet High ('H'), Low ('L') or Sevens ('S'). Your code should
// accept
// either capital or lowercase answers, but should display an error if the user
// attempts
// to enter anything but one of these 3 values and prompt for a valid answer.
// Return the character to the calling program.
private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    String userChoice = "";
    while (i == 0) {
        System.out.println("High, low or sevens (H/L/S): ");
        userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (userChoice.length() > 1 || (userChoice.charAt(0) != 'H' && userChoice.charAt(0) != 'h'
                && userChoice.charAt(0) != 'L' && userChoice.charAt(0) != 'l' && userChoice.charAt(0) != 'S'
                && userChoice.charAt(0) != 's')) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: You must type H, L, or S.");
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    char highLow = 'N';
    if (userChoice.charAt(0) == 'H' || userChoice.charAt(0) == 'h') {
        highLow = 'H';
    } else if (userChoice.charAt(0) == 'L' || userChoice.charAt(0) == 'l') {
        highLow = 'L';
    } else {
        highLow = 'S';
    }
    return highLow;
}

// Produce a random roll of a single six-sided die and return that value to the
// calling
// program
private static int getRoll() {
    int dieOne = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    System.out.println("Die 1 rolls: " + dieOne);
    int dieTwo = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    System.out.println("Die 2 rolls: " + dieTwo);
    int rollSum = dieOne + dieTwo;
    System.out.println("The total of two dice is: " + rollSum);
    return rollSum;
}

// Given the choice of high, low or sevens, the player's bet and the total
// result of
// the roll of the dice, determine how much the player has won. If the player
// loses
// the bet then winnings should be negative. If the player wins, the winnings
// should
// be equal to the bet if the choice is High or Low and 4 times the bet if the
// choice
// was Sevens. Return the winnings to the calling program.
private static int determineWinnings(char highLow, int bet, int roll) {
    int highLowValue = 0;
    int winnings = 0;
    if (highLow == 'H') {
        highLowValue = 8;
    } else if (highLow == 'L') {
        highLowValue = 6;
    } else {
        highLowValue = 7;
    }
    if (roll >= 8 && highLowValue == 8) {
        winnings = bet;
        System.out.println("You won " + winnings + " dollars!");
    } else if (roll <= 6 && highLowValue == 6) {
        winnings = bet;
        System.out.println("You won " + winnings + " dollars!");
    } else if (roll == 7 && highLowValue == 7) {
        winnings = bet * 4;
        System.out.println("You won " + winnings + " dollars!");
    } else {
        winnings = -1 * bet;
    }
    return winnings;

}
```

Comment: In `main`, assign the value to a variable: `int roll = getRoll();` and then pass `roll` to the `determineWinnings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the output of each method to variable or call methods directly on determineWinnings.

plan 1)

```
int userBet = getBet(keyboard, currentPool);
char highLow = getHighLow(keyboard);
int roll = getRoll();
determineWinnings(highLow, userBet, roll);
```

plan 2)

```
determineWinnings(getHighLow(keyboard), getBet(keyboard, currentPool), getRoll());
```

Answer (score -1):

There are following approaches to get the result of one method to another.

1. Pass result of one method to another
2. Define private/static members

Better way would be passing result of one method to another method.

Comment: Number 1 on your answer is what OP is asking *how to do*